# Error about ruby & rvm default version

Tags: ruby

on a CentOS 6.5 server, I installed ruby through rvm and set the `ruby-2.0.0-p451` as default.

> $ rvm --default ruby-2.0.0-p451

However, when I'm running script from Crontab
I got an error like

```
`require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
```

so I checked `ruby -v test.rb`, it tells me that I'm using `ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [x86_64-linux]` not the default `ruby-2.0.0-p451`. And I also checked with `/usr/bin/ruby`.

> $ /usr/bin/ruby -v
>   ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [x86_64-linux]

My question is how to use `ruby-2.0.0-p451`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simply changed the /usr/bin/ruby as a link to solve the problem as below:

> mv /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/_ruby
>
> ln -s /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, your path variable is not set correctly. It is generally defined in your ~/.profile, it should contain something like these 2 lines:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads R
```